# Amazon API ItemSearch Categories

Tags: php

I am using PHP PEAR Amazon package to retrieve products from the API, I can search for Books and DVDS at the moment, but I need all the categories, the problem is I cant find all the categories like e.g. home & garden.

I am using below code to pull out Books:

```
$result = $amazon->ItemSearch('Books', $options);
```

I have tried replacing books with Home&Garden but doesnt work, I need a full list of Amazon cats, anyone have any ideas where I can get these from I have trawled the Amazon site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?APPNDX_SearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html) are lists of possible SearchIndexes per locale and what parameters they accept.
"HomeGarden" should be what you're looking for..

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was after could find it for love nor money!

Comment: Link seems to be redirecting to the API overview